# Selenium Automation got error when trying to fill a field (Please refer to the question)

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, automation, automated-tests

I got this error when I trying to fill a field using Selenium. This is my code

[image]

Then, this is the error that I got!

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde371..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Fadhil\AppData\Loc...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55787}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 72.0.3626.119, webStorageEnabled: true}
    Session ID: 5dbac0e10fd42bd5afd533746e8abbb9
    *** Element info: {Using=id, value=frameId}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:372)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
        at Automation.Sitefinity.main(Sitefinity.java:60)
```

Comment: Post your html Code..

Comment: @Dhru'soni what u mean?

Comment: that means provide more information, Provide your html code with this questions, so  we can get the resolution over your questions.

Comment: Did you tried to click or clear that field first? @FadhilPratama

Answer (score 0):

To switch to a frame in Java, try this syntax:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(id);
```

where id is the webelement's (the frame's) ID.